# react-native with Hermes (android) using Realm: Crash on startup

Tags: android, realm, react-native, react-native-hermes

I've been building an app in React-Native. It initially was a 0.60 project, and over the course of development I have upgraded it several times and not it's on 0.63.4.

I noticed that, when running a release build on Android, the app feels really slow. It feels like it's eating up all the phone's memory. When I run it in Android Studio and attach a profiler, all seems normal though (+- 15% CPU usage, 128mb memory usage).

I tried adding Hermes to my app to see if it would make any difference, but as soon as I set the `enableHermes` parameter to true, clean & build, my app crashes without any error message (after a successful build) as soon as it launches.

I then went to React-Native's docs, where an alert said that each Hermes release is aimed at a specific RN version. Fine, I thought. React 0.63.x has Hermes version 0.5.3. Whenever I go to my yarn.lock and set `hermes-engine "0.5.3"`, it said it cannot find it and asks me which version I want to install instead.

I'm puzzled.

**Question**
What version of Hermes is appropriate for React-Native 0.63.4, and How do I add it appropriately to prevent the no-error-message crashes I'm getting now?

**UPDATE**
When running my app through Android Studio, I saw in the run log that it gave this message after opening and before crashing:

```
    E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: librealmreact.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found result: 0
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
    Process: com.dartscores, PID: 14692
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: librealmreact.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found result: 0
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:896)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:725)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:649)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:629)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:577)
        at io.realm.react.RealmReactModule.<clinit>(RealmReactModule.java:56)
        at io.realm.react.RealmReactPackage.createNativeModules(RealmReactPackage.java:31)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactPackageHelper.getNativeModuleIterator(ReactPackageHelper.java:42)
        at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:42)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:1347)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackages(ReactInstanceManager.java:1318)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1225)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:131)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1016)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

This indicated that something is wrong with loading the Realm dependency I'm using in my app? When I set the enableHermes back to false again, I don't get this message and everything seems to be running fine (but with poor performance).

Has anybody any experience with libraries not being able to be loaded when using Hermes?

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: hermes's correctversion is detected automatically by react-native when you enable it ... I'd suggest you clear-build-folder

Comment: Hi @HendEl-Sahli, I already did that and doing it again does not change anything. Would you have any other recommendations?

Comment: my suggestions ... 1. hermes requires some additional setup if proguard is enabled ... 2. If it was working fine before your upgrade, try to test it in different physical-devices and see if the error persists ... 3. create a new project (using latest version) and move your source-code to it and see if the issue is still there (cause It's likely that there's something wrong with your react-native upgrade)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but recreating the project is not helping either

Comment: Try to upgrade to the latest realm version (beta version)...

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that, as stated [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/2455#issuecomment-715650281), Realm does not support Hermes and the team is struggling to get it done. Seems like I need to switch databases..